PowerBI Combining data from two columns with different dates
I am relatively new to PowerBI, so apologies if there is a simple solution I'm missing here. I have weekly timesheets created in a canvas app within Project for the Web. I'm trying to create monthly summaries of the data, but this is challenging because a week might start in one month and end in another. I've managed to set up columns to calculate what falls where, but it means that I basically have columns as follows:



Person
Project
Month 1
Month 1 Hours
Month 2
Month 2 Hours




Person A
Project 1
Jan-24
15
Feb-24
5


Person A
Project 2
Jan-24
3
Feb-24
0


Person A
Project 3
Feb-24
10
Mar-24
1


Person B
Project 2
Jan-24
30
Feb-24
0


Person C
Project 1
Feb-24
21
Mar-24
7


Person C
Project 3
Jan-24
5
Feb-24
2


Person C
Project 4
Feb-24
1
Mar-24
3



I want to consolidate the hours across the months, but without losing the person & project breakdown. In other words, I want to see the total hours booked to a project within a month by each individual.
Any suggestions of how I can do this?
p.s. I should explain that the timesheet uses a start date for the week and then "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" etc.
Thanks!
I've tried a few different approaches, but I'm quite new to PowerBI and this has got me stumped. If I use the Month as the X-axis on a graph and then Month 1 hours and Month 2 hours as the Y-axis then I end up with Month 2 hours being associated to Month 1, which isn't right (e.g. for row 1 above, this would give 20 in Jan, rather than 15 hours in Jan and 5 in Feb.

I would start by trying to get a table of what you know at the DATE level. You know the week start date is 7/21/24, so, the Tuesday in that week is 7/23/24, etc.  I would have wanted the Canvas app to save the data that way, but, if it didn't, then you'll need to find a formula for that in Power Query or Dax.  If you needed more help on that, you should post example records of the data itself.
Once you have the data by date, then you just need a date table (I use this one from Radacad).  Join based on date, and then you can make reports using the Date / Week / Month fields from the Date table with no problem.
